Should I remove thinset globs between tile and tub deck and side walls?
Do I need to remove dried thinset globs between tile and tub deck, corners?
Should I remove dried thinset globs between tile and tub deck, corners?  If so, how?  Worried about puncturing the waterproofing.  And what’s the best strategy for avoiding this in the future?  I kept 99% of the thinset off the face of the tiles with a sponge and bucket, and scraped between joints (including tub deck and side walls) with one of those yellow plastic thinset removal tools.  But it wasn’t deep enough in some areas.  

Do as much as you can. Any increase in depth will provide a stronger grout joint. Use a narrow metal chisel to loosen the mortar. If it comes off easily, you've progressed.

What are we looking at?

@RMDman These are tile joints. They are substantial.
